# Good workflow for updating R modules around R-cran updates?

Tags: package-management, updates, cron, automation, r

I like that R updates frequently to give me the best new packages, but it does seem to pose a problem for my R scripts on cron schedules.

I noticed that every time ubuntu updater updates my r-base package, when I try to run my scripts, it'll say something like "`there is no library(XML)`".

Then I have to go "`update.packages("XML")`" to get the new version of that package that is compatible with my new version of R.

I have a lot of packages installed, so I find myself fairly regularly tracking them down and making long commands like "`update.packages(c("XML", "ggplot2", "timeseries"))`".

When I forget to do this after an update, all my R cron scripts fail.

Does anyone have a good workflow for automatically checking which packages I have already installed, and updating them when they need to be updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an `install.packages()` call in your cron script, so that it installs all current packages before it runs the rest of your R cron jobs.

`install.packages` takes a vector, so you could even keep the file with the packages you want installed elsewhere and then load it automatically in your cron update script.

`installed.packages()` returns a vector of already-installed packages, so you can use `%in%` to just call it on packages not yet installed:

```
desired.packages <- c("plyr","taRifx","ggplot2")
missing.packages <- ! desired.packages %in% installed.packages()[,1]
if( any(missing.packages) ) { 
   install.packages( desired.packages[missing.packages] )
}
```

**Edit: Possibly better solution**

As per @JoshuaUlrich's [suggestion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3931626#3931626):

Place this in your .Rprofile.

```
local({
  .libPaths("/home/evilgenius/R/library")
})
```

Then you should be able to just run `update.packages()` after Ubuntu wipes everything, and the monarchy will be restored.

This solution requires greater caution that packages that don't work with the current version of R aren't carried along.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that will likely do it.  Also, Josh Ulrich remains a very helpful super wizard.

Comment: @Mittenchops Indeed.  Between `hadley()` and `JU()`, my problems solve themselves these days. :-O